# The following prevent me from using sos, help

Tags: windbg, sos

Failed to load data access DLL, 0x80004005
Verify that 1) you have a recent build of the debugger (6.2.14 or newer)
            2) the file mscordacwks.dll that matches your version of mscorwks.dll is 
                in the version directory
            3) or, if you are debugging a dump file, verify that the file 
                mscordacwks_.dll is on your symbol path.
            4) you are debugging on the same architecture as the dump file.
                For example, an IA64 dump file must be debugged on an IA64
                machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[windbg\] Failed to load data access DLL, 0x80004005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920712/windbg-failed-to-load-data-access-dll-0x80004005)

Comment: Is it a dump file that you are debugging? If so how did you generate the crash dump file?

Answer (score 1):

CLR related information is accessed from windbg by sos/psscor using a data access component called mscordacwks. 
You can learn more details from here
http://blogs.msdn.com/dougste/archive/2009/02/18/failed-to-load-data-access-dll-0x80004005-or-what-is-mscordacwks-dll.aspx