# C# stackoverflow exception

Tags: c#

I had a stack overflow exception and i was able to use windbg to get a log of everything, however the log is very greek to me, and i'm not sure what i'm looking for.  Any help is appreciated.

```
FAULTING_IP: 
+1d42faf00b2df58
02dbb89f e9e3000000      jmp     02dbb987

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 791a2c0c (clr!EECodeManager::EnumGcRefs+0x0000001b)
   ExceptionCode: c00000fd (Stack overflow)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000001
   Parameter[1]: 02dd2edc

PROCESS_NAME:  crawler.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc00000fd - A new guard page for the stack cannot be created.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc00000fd - A new guard page for the stack cannot be created.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000001

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  02dd2edc

RECURRING_STACK: From frames 0x19 to 0x19

MOD_LIST: <ANALYSIS/>

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
No export dumpstack found

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 791a2fad to 791a2c0c

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffff

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NOSOS

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NOSOS

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NOSOS_STACK_OVERFLOW_STACKIMMUNE

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000 00000000 crawler.exe+0x0


SYMBOL_NAME:  crawler.exe

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: crawler

IMAGE_NAME:  crawler.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4e5a416f

STACK_COMMAND:  ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NOSOS_c00000fd_crawler.exe!Unknown

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NOSOS_STACK_OVERFLOW_STACKIMMUNE_crawler.exe

FOLLOWUP_IP: *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for crawler.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for crawler.exe

crawler+0
00400000 4d              dec     ebp

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/crawler_exe/1_0_0_0/4e5a416f/clr_dll/4_0_30319_1/4ba1d9ef/c00000fd/00062c0c.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0:005> .exr 0xffffffffffffffff
ExceptionAddress: 791a2c0c (clr!EECodeManager::EnumGcRefs+0x0000001b)
   ExceptionCode: c00000fd (Stack overflow)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000001
   Parameter[1]: 02dd2edc
```

Comment: Stack trace? What code is causing the problem?

Comment: What is your question? Step through the code and post the actual exception and line it falls over on.

Comment: If you plan on debugging C# from windbg please load SOS.  I would default to C# Express if you are debugging C# though.  It is free and more user friendly if you are unfamiliar windbg.

Comment: that's the whole problem i have no idea what was causing the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load SOS (`.loadby sos clr` or `.loadby sos mscorwks` if you're not on .NET 4) and use the `!pe` command to display the exception. If you don't have the exception object, use `!threads` to list the threads and any exceptions they may have.

Answer (score 3):

Work out what the process was doing at the time, and look for either:

- Deliberately recursive methods which might have recursed beyond where they were meant to
- Accidentally recursive properties like this:

  ```
  private readonly string foo;
  public string Foo { get { return Foo; } } // Should have been return foo;
  ```

Ideally, you should have unit tests which can help to pin this down - they're normally pretty good at finding such problems. The unit test running may still crash (StackOverflowException can't be caught) but it should help to isolate it.

I would personally have a few goes at reproducing the problem in conventional ways before going for advanced debugging techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try DebugDiag first - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26798. It will do automatic analysis of your dump.

If that's not enough you will need SOS to analyze .NET code - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx.

Here you can find some info on how to load it - [Unable to load SOS in WinDbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373683/unable-to-load-sos-in-windbg).

Then just use one of the commands to analyze dump. Tess Fernandez has great tutorials on how to use windbg with sos - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/tags/debugging/.

She also published labs to help you learn windbg - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx.

If your dump is from different system then the one you analyze on this might help - [Is it possible to debug win2003 IIS crash dump using windbg on windows XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153861/is-it-possible-to-debug-win2003-iis-crash-dump-using-windbg-on-windows-xp)